# jquery niceScroll. При создании скрола, елемент с прокруткой не туда ставится

Tags: jquery

Добрый день. Подскажите есть ли нюанс работы плагина[image: при создании скрола в списке, сам плагин добавляет DOM для скрола вниз ul, не по соседству в li где я создаю скрол]

Почему? Мне пока неясно какой цсс или js код использовать для устранения проблемы.

Функция создания скрола.

`//вызов вертикального скролла для списков

var niceScrollProcesses = function(selector) {
    selector.niceScroll({
        cursorcolor: "#1FB5AD",
        cursorborder: "0px solid #fff",
        cursorborderradius: "0px",
        cursorwidth: "3px",
        fixed: true,
        autohidemode: false
    });
};`

Comment: В чем проблема-то? В том, что у вас скроллбар унесло влево?

Comment: Да, не влево а под низ. хоча ето работающий и код и он должен по соседству с елементом ставить скрол.

Comment: Вы уверены, что не влево? Я вот вижу бесхозный скроллбар наверху колонки *TurboJapan*.

Comment: Чисто по скрину мне кажется, что какая-то проблема в DOM. У вас колонки генерируются или это статика пока?

Comment: Да уверен. #ascrail2005 Єто правильный тег. он внутри верхней секции. Возможно чуть не коректный скрин. Но смысл остается. Добавляеш скрол к этому div выделеному. и он будет вставлен гдето внизу, а не в этом списке. Вопрос почему? может чтото ему не хватает

Comment: Это не статика.